# Can't terminate the for loop when winning a word guessing game

Tags: c, loops, break

I have written code for a **word guessing game**;

1. The code takes a random word from a file of words, within the file, there is "1" word per line.
2. The code then converts this word into asterisks and displays it when the code is run.
3. It prompts whoever runs the programme to input a letter. If the letter is correct, the asterisks corresponding to that letter will become that letter. If not, the programme prompts for another guess.

The number of tries is set by the user when the programme is running. The programme is called **wordguess** so on command prompt it is run using **"wordguess filename.txt n"**.

**filename.txt** refers to the file containing the words to choose from. **n** refers to the number of tries the user is allowed before losing the game. I can get the game to finish if the person does not guess the word within the chosen number of tries but I can't seem to get the game to finish if the person has won. If the word is correctly guessed, the loop will still continue till the person runs out of guesses. I am not sure what condition to place on the loop to facilitate a win. I have tried various if statements but the code does not run when I try that.

```
    //taking random word from file
    srand(time(0));
    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    while (!feof(f))
    {
        fgets(word, 1024, f);
        word[strcspn(word, "\n")] = '\0';
        nL++;
    }
    randomline = rand() % nL;
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    for (i = 0; !feof(f) && i <= randomline; i++)
        fgets(word, 1024, f);
        word[strcspn(word, "\n")] = '\0';
    strcpy(astword, word); //copies word to another char
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(astword); i++)
    {
        astword[i] = '*'; //copy is converted to asterisks
    }
    int counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < tries; i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n", astword);
        printf("guess a letter\n");
        scanf(" %c", &guess);
        for (i = 0; i < tries; i++)
{
    printf("%s \n", astword);
    printf("guess a letter\n");
    scanf(" %c", &guess);

    for (j = 0; j < tries; j++)
    {
        if (guess == word[j])
            astword[j] = guess;
    }   
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

**Edit:** According to Ozan's answer, I have modified my loop but it doesn't seem to be working;

```
        for (j = 0; j < tries; j++)
        {

            if (guess == word[j]) 
            {
                astword[j] = guess;
                counter++; 
            }

            if (counter == strlen(astword))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: "Am I missing something obvious?" unfortunately yes. But you are not alone. There is an overwhelming number of people learning programming who have the exact same problem as you: you don't know how to **debug**. Debugging is paramount to programming. You can't advance without it. You must take the time to learn how to debug. And then it will save you countless hours of just staring at your program wondering why it doesn't work. You need to debug your own programs and you will at least narrow down the problem significantly and can ask a more specific question than "my program doesn't work"

Comment: also, your paragraph is a wall of text. Please be mindful of this and structure your statements.

Comment: just in case I wasn't understood: the obvious thing that you are missing is that you need to debug your program.

Comment: I agree, after reading your comment I understand the need to set aside time to learn how to debug. Thanks.

Comment: `fseek` in a text file with variable-length words is suspicious. Suggest you read the entire text into memory and break it up into pieces?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you just want to find the correct logic to terminate your **for loop**. If you want to terminate the loop when user guessed all the letters correctly, you can manage it via counting how many **asterisk->letter** replacements did your program made and when the count is reached to the number of your word's letters, then it is time to terminate the loop, because it means that there is no more asterisks to guess and the word is guessed correctly with all of its missing letters..

In the below code block from your program(*where the replacement is happening*);

```
for (j = 0; j < tries; j++){
    if (guess == word[j])
      astword[j] = guess;
}
```

Just add a **counter** to count how many times an **asterisk(*)** is replaced with a **letter**;

```
for (j = 0; j < tries; j++){
  if (guess == word[j]){
    astword[j] = guess;
    counter++; // int variable, initialized to 0 before for loop starts
  }
}
```

And at the start of the outer **for loop**, add an **if statement** to check if  `counter`  is equals to `strlen(astword)`;

```
if (counter == strlen(astword))
      break; // if the replacement action is occured with the same number of word's lenght, break the loop.
```

So as the combination of the above codes, your **for loop** must be handling the break situation like this;

```
for (i = 0; i < tries; i++){
    if (counter == strlen(astword))
      break;
    printf("%s \n", astword);
    printf("guess a letter\n");
    scanf(" %c", &guess);

    for (j = 0; j < tries; j++)
    {
        if (guess == word[j]){
            astword[j] = guess;
            counter++;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I have attempted your suggestion and modified the code in the question however I still cannot break the loop. Have I followed your advice incorrectly?

Comment: You have 2 mistakes, you should be opening brackets for `if (guess == word[j])`. And also `if (counter == strlen(astword))` must be inside the for loop, not outside. Check the last part of my answer, there is the working form of the code.

Comment: I've tried again and edited the question again. I still find that the loop is not broken.

Comment: Oh my bad, I've read your code wrong, please check the last part of my answer, I edited it.